# How to make the title a link and some errors

Tags: python, discord.py, aiohttp

```
import aiohttp
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random


Token = ""
YOUR_PREFIX = "-"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=YOUR_PREFIX)


@client.command()
async def server(ctx):
    name = str(ctx.guild.name)
    description = str(ctx.guild.description)

    owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
    # id = str(ctx.guild.id)
    region = str(ctx.guild.region)
    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)

    icon = str(ctx.guild.icon_url)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=name,
        description=description,
        color=discord.Color.blurple()
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=icon)
    embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
    # embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def reddit(ctx, subr="memes"):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Here u go sire it is mi duty to make u laugh", description="HAHA, that was funny ngl")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/'+subr+'/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Here u go sire it is mi duty to make u laugh", description="HAHA, that was funny ngl")
            embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'][random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
client.run(Token)
```

I  would like to make the title the title or the subreddit and make it a link for the reddit post

```
Ignoring exception in command reddit:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 46, in reddit
    embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'][random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
KeyError: 'data'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'data'
```

the above are the errors I am getting this error for some other subreddits like karens as well indiandankmemes etc
I am a bit confused with the errors and some help could be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe discord embeds support markdown, so you can use `[Title](Link)` to make it redirect you to the link.

This is what it might look like:

```py
import aiohttp
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random


Token = ""
YOUR_PREFIX = "-"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=YOUR_PREFIX)


@client.command()
async def server(ctx):
    name = str(ctx.guild.name)
    description = str(ctx.guild.description)

    owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
    # id = str(ctx.guild.id)
    region = str(ctx.guild.region)
    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)

    icon = str(ctx.guild.icon_url)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=name,
        description=description,
        color=discord.Color.blurple()
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=icon)
    embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
    # embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def reddit(ctx, subr="memes"):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Here u go sire it is mi duty to make u laugh", description="HAHA, that was funny ngl")
    # This part is changed
    url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/" + subr + "/new.json?sort=hot"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get(url) as r:
            res = await r.json()

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"[Here u go sire it is mi duty to make u laugh]({url})", description="HAHA, that was funny ngl")
            embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'][random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
client.run(Token)
```